# How to set interval for Server-Sent Event without using sleep()

Tags: php, mysql, eventsource

I'm trying to do a Server-Sent Event to keep update the database when the client page active. To prevent mysql heavy loading, I decide to use sleep(10) to make interval. But I found that sleep() function cause performance issue. I would like to know any method can replace sleep to make interval.

Issues facing:

1.Reload page take long time.
2.While sleep other page unable to process.

Below is my sample code that I using currently.

```
 header('Content-Type: text/event-stream');
 header('Cache-Control: no-cache');

    $updated_time = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");

    $sql = "UPDATE mytable SET alive='$updated_time' WHERE status='active'";       
    runSql($sql);

    echo "data: {$updated_time} \n\n";

    sleep(10);    

    flush();
```

Comment: What if you flush and then sleep?

Comment: Having same issue

Comment: send "retry: 10000", close the connection